# Error when using ajax load google map api

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I have a file index.php using jquery:

```
<div id="nav"><a href="#"><input type="hidden" value="36.753671,-119.768336" />test</a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav a').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
        var dataString = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'map.php',
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html) {
                $('.map').html(html);
           } 
        });
    });
});
<div class="map"></div>
```

in map.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/mapsfile=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true_or_false&amp;key=ABQIAAAA" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 200; height: 200px"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $id ?>), 16);
            map.setUIToDefault();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

> When I enter input id=('36.753671,-119.768336') is ajax not result,
>   Can I help me ? I want this ideas

Answer (score 1):

I see that the script tage in map.php is within PHP code which should not be. Two ways to fix.
1)

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
?> //close php tag here
```

```
    <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 200; height: 200px"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $id ?>), 16);
            map.setUIToDefault();
        }
    }
    </script>
```

2)

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
   echo '<script src="http://maps.google.com/mapsfile=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true_or_false&amp;key=ABQIAAAA" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 200; height: 200px"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?php echo $id ?>), 16);
            map.setUIToDefault();
        }
    }
    </script>';
```

Comment: And please also call map.php in the browser and make sure it does not throws any errors. Change the method from $_POST to $_GET and see if you have proper response.